# PHP getting webpage that requires javascript to load

Tags: javascript, php

So i'm trying to obtain the HTML Source of a page via PHP by doing the following:

```
$doc = file_get_contents('http://myanimelist.net/animelist/0000RIP0000');
var_dump($doc);
```

but as I understood, this specific page only loads by Javascript, that is, it won't return the HTML I want because PHP dosn't render the javascript part.

Comment: use a headless browser

Comment: The url you specified does have normal HTML source content and load nicely without JavaScript. Maybe some features won't work, but the page in general seems to load properly. Maybe your server is not configured to allow `file_get_contents` to be used on urls. You'll need to enable [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php).

Comment: Sorry, that was only sort of a very lame joke.

Comment: @charlietfl I'm gonna search more about those headless browsers, it may be just what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Mink](https://github.com/minkphp/docs/blob/master/index.rst) (browser emulator) with [SeleniumHQ](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) (browser automation) to load and run javascript on the page. Then extract the emulated page content by injecting a javascript that scans the emulated DOM for the content you want. Mink will let you do it from within your PHP server.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript will never ever be rendered, because it is run on the client-side.
If the javascript is running on the target server and fails on your server,
check, if you have all the needed external javascript files.

Comment: JavaScript can run on the server too, although it's not easy from PHP, but I don't think you really understood the problem (maybe even OP didn't).

Comment: I understood it as the content I want is post page loading in the client, so it is only normal that the server where I run the PHP can't get the contents I need.